# Как реализовать вывод результата без обновления страницы

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог ввести цифры, например `$sum1 = 1500; $sum2 = 100;` и т.д.
Все это реализовал через форму.
Эти переменные должны сложится и получится результат: `$resilt = $sum1+$sum2;`

Это то все реализовал. но у меня получается что вывод результата происходит в отдельном файле. 
Форма :

```
<form action="result.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
тут поля для ввода
<input class="calculate" type="submit" name="calc" value="Сложить" />
</form>
```

А мне нужно чтобы результат появился без обновления страницы.

Вот есть небольшой код, он выполняет ссылку без перезагрузки страницы, но как сделать это для формы я не совсем понимаю:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "result.php",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(response){
                $("#content").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно в ajax запросе передать данные `data` из формы. 
Данные из формы можно получить например по `id` формы

`var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("myform"));`

В результате. Допустим у вас есть форма

```
<form id="myform" method="POST" action="#">
// тут поля формы
</form>
```

ajax:

```
 $("#link").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // отмена дефолтного действия для ссылки

        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("myform"));
        $.ajax({
            url: "result.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: formData,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(response){
                $("#content").html(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

Большинство правда передают данные так:

```
var sum1 = $('id первого инпута').val();
var sum2 = $('id второго инпута').val();
```

Т.е. берут данные из каждого элемента формы и заносят в отдельные переменные, а потом эти переменные уже заносят в поле `data`, которое отсылают серверу при аякс запросе

`data: {sum1: sum1, sum2: sum2}`

Comment: получается что при нажатии на кнопку страница обновляется, и к ссылке добавляет #

Comment: Так вы и не сабмитьте форму. Вы обрабатывайте клик по кнопке. Или у вас там `link` это ссылка? Тогда добавьте  `e.preventDefault();`  в начале функции. Подправил ответ для вас...... Сами данные с формы отправились-то хоть?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/event/preventDefault) для отмены стандартного события:

```
$("#link").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   // ...
});
```